# Breeze can't configure metadata right

Tags: json, breeze, edmx

I'm trying to get breeze running but i'm new to this stuff, so i have some problems.

**Snippet of my Metafata:**

from `http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/$metadata`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<edmx:Edmx Version="1.0" 
    xmlns:edmx="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/06/edmx">
    <edmx:DataServices m:DataServiceVersion="1.0" m:MaxDataServiceVersion="3.0" 
        xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
        <Schema Namespace="NAV" 
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/05/edm">
            <EntityType Name="contact">
                <Key>
                    <PropertyRef Name="No" />
                </Key>
                <Property Name="No" Type="Edm.String" Nullable="false" />
                <Property Name="Type" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Company_No" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Company_Name" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="IntegrationCustomerNo" Type="Edm.String" />
                <Property Name="Name" Type="Edm.String" />
```

**If i set:** `hasServerMetadata: true,` then breeze tries to connect to: `http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company('CRONUS%20(Schweiz)%20AG')/Metadata`
instead of where it is:
`http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/$metadata`

**Snippet of my Json i get:** from

`http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/Company('CRONUS%20(Schweiz)%20AG')/customer?$format=json`

```
{
    "odata.metadata": "http://localhost:7048/DynamicsNAV71/OData/$metadata#customer",
    "value": [
        {
            "No": "01121212",
            "Name": "Spotsmeyer's Furnishings",
            "Address": "612 South Sunset Drive",
            "Address_2": "",
            "Post_Code": "US-FL 37125",
```

**I also tried the following:**

```
var manager = new breeze.EntityManager({ dataService: dataService });
initializeMetadataStore(manager.metadataStore);

function initializeMetadataStore(metadataStore) {
    var et = new breeze.EntityType({
        shortName: "customer",
        namespace: "what.Models"
    });
    et.addProperty( new breeze.DataProperty({
        name: "No",
        dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
        isNullable: false,
        isPartOfKey: true,
    }));
    et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
        name: "Name",
        dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
        isNullable: true,
    }));
    et.addProperty(new breeze.DataProperty({
        name: "Address",
        dataType: breeze.DataType.String,
        isNullable: true,
    }));
    metadataStore.addEntityType(et);
}
```

**I try to display them with:**

```
<p data-bind="visible: !results">Fetching data ... </p>
<ul data-bind="foreach: results, visible: results" style="display:none">
  <li>
    <span data-bind="text:Name"></span>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**But i get the Error:** `Name not defined`
If i replace the Name with value: `<span data-bind="text:value"></span>` i can see one li with a lot of `object Objects`

Any hints?

Best Regards

Answer (score 0):

Have you configured the breeze's adapter?

```
// "Standard" Web API OData source (e.g., WCF OData)
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'odata', true);
```

or

```
// ASP.NET Web API OData
breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('dataService', 'webApiOData', true);
```

Please also check that you are not using `camelCase` naming convention

```
breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
```